# Not able to write any contain into log file though empty file created

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Used the below configuration to log the message to both console and file. I could see only the console output. Though file created but it does not have any contain

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = C:/target/rolling/rollingtest.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %-5p [%t] %x %c %M - %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = C:/target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %-5p [%t] %x %c %M - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1KB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.example.my.app
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your properties and they seem okay to me. Consider the following:

- To catch messages to file you need your code to produce `debug` messages
- To catch messages to file your log messages have to be produced from the classes having fully qualified names starting from `com.example.my.app`

Here is the example that worked:

```
package com.example.my.app;


import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    Logger getLogger(){
        return logger;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main mainObj = new Main();
        mainObj.getLogger().debug("test debig");
    }

}
```